# OnSensorChane not being called in some devices

Tags: android, foreground-service, sensormanager, pedometer

I have tried integrating pedometer.
I have came across one issue that onSensorChanges is not being called in specifically **ONEPLUS 8**
Can any one help ?

I am registering listener as below

```
 sensorManager.registerListener(SensorService.this, sSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Not adding full code as it is working in other device liek Samsung A50.

Comment: What type of a sensor is `sSensor` here? Not all devices have all the sensors, but I suppose the accelerometer at least should exist on all phones. A "step detector" or "step counter" might not.

Comment: It is of step detector type

Comment: I would highly recommend confirming if the device has Step Detecting sensor/ pedometer sensor. There are many devices which do not have an inbuilt pedometer.